# Check if each item in a list belongs to certain group and create a new list

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have a list of stored ids. I need to group these id into a separate group of list based on if each id belongs to certain group. For instance in below example, I would like to return:

```
List<Group1> = {1,2};
List<Group2> = {3,4};
List<Group3> = {5};
```

Now I have hundreds of group, so i can't literally create a group and add items to that group. So, how can I create and return these groups dynamically?

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };   
foreach (int i in list)
{
 var x = PersonList.GetById(I); //Returns Person object
 var obj = x.GroupBy(y => y.GroupName).ToList();
// where obj is IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,Person>>
// I can get Group1 from Person object
//how to get List<Group2> ...and so on?
}
```

Comment: But why should 1 & 2 be in the first list and 3 & 4 in the next list. How will you decide that?

Comment: Group1,Group2 are records in Person table. So when I do var obj = x.GroupBy(y => y.GroupName).ToList(); I can get Group1 from x. basically obj is IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,Person>>

Comment: Can you show your `Person` and `Group1`, `Group2`, `Group3` classes' code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this

```
var obj = x.GroupBy(y => y.GroupName); // IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,Person>>
```

Now in order to get list that belongs to certain group you need to check the IGrouping's key with your own key (that you used to make grouping).

```
var group2 = obj.Where(g => g.Key == "Group2").SelectMany(g => g).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want your persons in groups, the query below will put them into a dictionary where the key of the dictionary will be the group name and the value will be a list of `Person` objects.

```
var groups = obj.ToDictionary( t => t.Key, t => t);
```